# How to add a string from a buffer to another array and print this?

Tags: c++, c, loops, buffer, fgets

So basically I want to write a word, and when I press enter I want to store this string from buffer to array. As I write the first word it might work but when I want to add a second word it is getting tricky.

```
e.g.1st input is:first\0
    2nd input is:two\0
    then:Ctrl+Z(to get out of the loop)
    Output I want:first two (actually printing the 'array' array.)
```

My Code is Here:

```
position=0;
printf("Enter a text: \n");
while(fgets(buffer, 100 , stdin) != NULL){
    for (i=position;i<(position+numberOfChars);i++){
        array[i]=buffer[i];
    }
    numberOfChars=strlen(buffer);
    position=position+numberOfChars+1;
}
```

Comment: C or C ++, because c++ container classes are much easier to use than, say malloc/realloc and pointer arrays/realloc.

Comment: You need to stop your for loop at the end of `buffer` or best when `buffer[i] == '\0'` perhaps add a space between words and finally add the final `\0` You can directly use `array + numberOfChars` in fgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See comments in the code:

```
position=0;
printf("Enter a text: \n");
while(fgets(buffer, 100 , stdin) != NULL){

    /* because you want to add space between 'first' and 'two' */ 
    if (position != 0) {
        array[position] = ' ';
        position++;
    }

    /* you need to get the buffer len for THIS iteration */
    numberOfChars=strlen(buffer);

    for (i=position;i<(position+numberOfChars);i++){
        /* i is a valid indice for array but not for buffer[0..numberOfChars-1] */
        /* array[i]=buffer[i]; */
        array[i] = buffer[i-position];
    }

    /* adding one will not add a space char */
    /* position=position+numberOfChars+1; */
    position = position+numberOfChars;
}

/* finaly add the null char at the end of the string (string is null terminated) */
array[position] = '\0';
```

You may also try this:

```
printf("Enter a text: \n");

/* set array as an empty string */
array[0] = 0;

/* read from stdin */
while(fgets(buffer, 100, stdin) != NULL) {

    /* append a space to array if it isn't empty */
    if (array[0] != 0) 
        strcat(array, " ");

    /* append buffer to array */
    strcat(array, buffer)
}

/* print resulting array */
printf("%s\n");
```

Comment: try to point out to where the error is  in the OP code and if you could add more explanation to benefit more folks in here...

Comment: Thanks you @OlivierPellier-Cuit for your solution it works fine! But when I print array
I am getting:'first two' one string in each line 

instead of: 'first two' all strings in one line

Is this a problem ?because I want count the words of the array

Comment: It's because fgets add a end of line char. You could remove it but it will not be a problem if you just want to count the words

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Note that fgets() stores the newline read from the stdin into the buffer as well. So, you want to get rid of it. *And* you want to put an extra space between the two words. Also, you are initializing numberOfChars too late. It should happen before it is used in the copy loop.

Try this:

```
position = 0;
printf("Enter a text: \n");
while(fgets(buffer, 100 , stdin) != NULL) {
    numberOfChars = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[numberOfChars - 1] = ' '; //this replaces newline with space
    // note that i <= in the condition; to copy the '\0' over
    for (i = position; i <= (position + numberOfChars); i++) {
        array[i] = buffer[i];
    }        
    position = position + numberOfChars;
}
```